# Dell Latitude 3490 - MDT results in "No Boot Device Found"

Tags: windows, partition, boot, wds, mdt

We recently got in a batch of a new (to us) model laptop, Dell Latitude 3490. Whenever I attempt to deploy Windows 10 (Education, version 1709 x64), I end up at "No boot device found. Press any key to reboot the machine".

I found, downloaded, and imported the [associated driver pack](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/12461.latitude-3490-windows-10-driver-pack) from Dell, and added that to the Windows 10 Selection Profile (which I verified as being used by this Task Sequence). We have other Dells and haven't needed it, but when this failed I added the Dell's [WinPE driver pack](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/4/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=942XJ) to MDT and set up a Selection Profile for the WinPE image to use.  I tried rebuilding with these BIOS options on and off:

- Legacy Option ROM
- Enable Legacy Boot
- Secure Boot
- SATA Operation (AHCI vs RAID)

The OptiPlex 3050s that we got in at the same time required the "Attempt Legacy Boot" option, which I was able to set as part of the MDT sequence - this option exists in the same place on the Latitude 3490s, but did not have the same affect.

I am getting 0 errors or warnings or otherwise bad vibes from PXE, WDS, or MDT. The build starts and progresses as expected through the Install Operating System step, and then goes to its reboot that should take it out of WinPE and into the OS to finish installing applications, but when it should boot to the internal drive it starts a diagnostic scan and then ends on "No boot device found".

By default (and this works on all other models), MDT tries to format BIOS and also UEFI - I tried disabling one or the other, no dice.

The drive itself works - I can see it in diskpart in WinPE, it shows up in the BIOS, the Windows that came on it works, and I can install the same Windows image from a base ISO on a USB drive.

When I successfully install Windows from a USB drive, Diskpart looks like this:
Volume -- Ltr -- Label -- Fs -- Type -- Size -- Status
Volume 0 -- C -- System Rese -- NTFS -- Partition -- 549MB -- Healthy
Volume 1 -- D -- -- NTFS -- Partition -- 118GB -- Healthy

I tried to recreate that as best as possible (disabling the default options):

[Format and Partition Disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLuoR.png)

No change with that. If I PXE back in to WinPE and check Diskpart, list volume shows basically identical, just with the Volume 1 (D:) being labeled OSDisk which is how it is named in MDT.

Versions and such

- DHCP: Windows Server 2008 R2 (options 66 and 67 set to point at the WDS box)
- WDS: Windows Server 2012 R2
- MDT: 8450
- Clients: Windows 10 Education, version 1709 x64

Comment: The most likely cause for that error is that when you ran MDT you booted it in UEFI mode, but you're trying to boot Windows in legacy mode, or vice versa.  You seem to have eliminated that already, but it might be worth double-checking.  See whether MDT installed the disk as GPT (which can only work in UEFI boot mode) or as MBR (which can only work in legacy boot mode) and make sure the boot settings are configured accordingly.

Comment: Don’t disable the two different partition steps (BIOS and UEFI). It works very simply like this. If you boot in MBR mode it will partition as MBR. If you boot in UEFI mode it will partition as UEFI. Let MDT handle this. Looks like you created a single partition step to force it to use MBR. Put the laptops in UEFI mode, boot and start the deployment.

Comment: I tried having them both enabled vs. just BIOS or just UEFI. However, I did find a breakthrough - I noticed that this model does not support booting to internal devices via legacy mode. I was able to enable UEFI network stack for the NIC in the BIOS settings page, and change the boot file in WDS, and it PXE'd via UEFI, and then was able to complete the deployment. In other environments I support the UEFI clients all tend to have UEFI PXE enabled already, and this hasn't been an issue. Now I just need to get WDS working with both legacy and UEFI at the same time.

Comment: I think I need to add a DHCP Policy to make it treat the legacy and UEFI clients differently. Currently I cannot do that as the DHCP server is 2008 R2 and that feature is new as of 2012. We're planning on upgrading (We already have the hardware) to 2016 this summer. We're also planning to get rid of most of the non-UEFI models with these new ones anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide some closure, this was the answer:

I had to add a DHCP Policy to treat legacy and UEFI clients differently. I had to wait until our DHCP server (2008 R2) was replaced with a (2016) new one sometime that summer. I basically followed this guide: https://gal.vin/2017/05/05/pxe-booting-for-uefi-bios/ . I'll repost the text here in case that URL goes down.

### Defining DHCP Vendor Classes

1. Go to DHCP, right-click on **IPv4**.
2. In the DHCP Vendor Classes window, click **Add**
3. For the Name enter **PXEClient (UEFI x86)**.
4. For the Description enter whatever you want.
5. Under the ASCII text enter **PXEClient:Arch:00006** (you will not be able to paste this text, and it’s also case-sensitive)
6. Click **OK** to add it to the list.
7. Now repeat steps 2 – 6 for **PXEClient (UEFI x64)** with **PXEClient:Arch:00007** as
   the ASCII value.
8. Finally, repeat steps 2 – 6 for **PXEClient (BIOS x86 & x64)** with **PXEClient:Arch:00000** (five zero’s) as the ASCII value.

### Defining DHCP Policies

1. Go to DHCP and expand the scope you wish to create a policy for.
2. Right-click on Policies and choose **New Policy**.
3. Enter **PXEClient (UEFI x64)** for the name.
4. Enter a Description, or leave it blank. Click **Next**.
5. On the Configure Conditions for the policy screen, click **Add**.
6. In the Add/Edit Condition window, click the **Value**: drop down menu.
7. Choose the **PXEClient (UEFI x64)** vendor class you created earlier.
8. Tick the **Append wildcard(*)** check box and then click Add and finally **OK**.
9. Click **Next** on the Configure Conditions for the policy screen.
10. On the Configure settings for the policy screen, click **No** for the Do you want to configure an IP address range for the policy. Click **Next**.
11. *Please Note*: if DHCP is on the same server as WDS, you will need to set option **060**, if WDS is on a different server, you do not need to set option **060**.
12. On the Configure settings for the policy screen, scroll down until you see options **060** (if applicable), **066** and **067**.
13. Tick option **060** and enter **PXEClient** if applicable.
14. Tick option **066** and enter either the **FQDN or the IP address of the WDS server**.
15. Tick option **067** and enter **boot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi** – this is the x64 UEFI boot file for WDS. Click Next.
16. On the Summary screen, if all the details are correct, click **Finish**.
17. Now repeat steps 2 – 14 for **PXEClient (UEFI x86)** with **boot\x86\wdsmgfw.efi** as option 067.
18. Finally, repeat steps 2 – 14 once again for **PXEClient (BIOS x86 & x64)** with **boot\x64\wdsnbp.com** as option 067 and leave option 060 empty.